# Kerberos Over HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, kerberos

I have a WCF service hosted by a Windows Application of my own. I want the service to authenticate the client at the transport level using the client's Certificate and when the client communicates with the service, it must pass its Kerberos Ticket of the client's user account. [Looking around on the internet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87d8d4db-4b56-4295-a2c6-b1b97c7e8f42/wcf-client-passing-2-client-authentication-tokens) i found this configuration for the service:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
         <binding name="Kerberos (MsgHeader) over Transport (Certificate)">
             <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                 <security authenticationMode="KerberosOverTransport">
                     <secureConversationBootstrap />
                 </security>
              <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
          </binding>
     </customBinding>
 </bindings>
```

They say that this configuration worked with Microsoft's help. Now, i tried to duplicate this configuration through code, so i used the following snippet:

```
BindingElementCollection elementCollection = new BindingElementCollection();
elementCollection.Add(SecurityBindingElement.CreateKerberosOverTransportBindingElement());
elementCollection.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11 });
elementCollection.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement() { RequireClientCertificate = true });

return new CustomBinding(elementCollection);
```

I configured the endpoint with this binding along with a valid certificate bound to the port. I then added a service reference at the client project in Visual Studio.

To this end, everthing is working great! I also configured the client to send its certificate when communicating with the service, this also worked fine. However, when I try to invoke any method of the service, I get the following error:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

And when I examined the inner exception, I found the following error:

> An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.

Any help, please? Do i need to configure the client further to send its Kerberos token, or what?

P.S. The service and client machine clocks are synchronized. In addition, the service and the client are on two different machines joined to a domain.

Comment: Have you made sure that the configuration-based approach works? I don't know if this will help at all, but I strongly suspect you should change your code to add the binding elements [in the *same order*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793.aspx) that the configuration does.

Comment: Isn't the order correct?

Comment: The configuration adds `textMessageEncoding` first, then `security`, then `httpsTransport`. The code swaps the first two. Though the link I just posted claims that the code's order is right.

Comment: Sorry dude, same exception!

Comment: OK, back to my other question then :) Does the configuration-based approach work *for you*?

Comment: Do you mean the file configuration, no that two also threw an exception? It didn't even start the service.